# Sum of the Roots of $(x-\sqrt2)^2(x+\sqrt3)(x-\sqrt5)=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find the sum of the roots of the following equation:
>   $$(x-\sqrt2)^2(x+\sqrt3)(x-\sqrt5)=0$$

I did $\sqrt2 - \sqrt3 + \sqrt5$ to get the answer.

My textbook says $2\sqrt2 - \sqrt3 + \sqrt5$ is the answer.

The roots of the equation, strictly speaking, are $\sqrt2, \sqrt3,$ and $\sqrt5$, and not $\sqrt2, \sqrt2, \sqrt3,$ and $\sqrt5$ right? So shouldn't my answer be correct?

Comment: the root $\sqrt{2}$ has multiplicity $2$, so there are $2$ copies of $\sqrt{2}$

Answer (score 3):

The question suffers from the vagueness of language.  To be fully precise, it could either have been phrased as:

> Find the sum of all roots (including multiplicity) of the following equation: $$(x-\sqrt{2})^2(x+\sqrt{3})(x-\sqrt{5})=0$$

or,

> Find the sum of all **distinct** roots of the following equation:  $$(x-\sqrt{2})^2(x+\sqrt{3})(x-\sqrt{5})=0$$